# Python CanOpen canGetNumberOfChannels not defined | kvaser canlib is unavailable

Tags: python

i tried to run my Python Program on my Linux maschine but when i try to run it it is having a hard time finding all the nessasary modules needed for it to work.
i installed CanOpen to my project

```
import threading
import sys

sys.path.append('venv/Lib/site-packages')
sys.path.append('venv/Lib/site-packages/can/interfaces/kvaser')
sys.path.append('/test/Python39/Lib')

import canopen
from canopen.network import MessageListener, NodeScanner
from canopen.nmt import NmtMaster
from canopen.sync import SyncProducer
from canopen.timestamp import TimeProducer


if __name__ == '__main__':
    network = canopen.Network()

    network.connect(bustype='kvaser', channel=0, bitrate=250000)
```

it is showing me following error in the Terminal:

```
Kvaser canlib is unavailable.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/test/Can_T1/main.py", line 60, in <module>
    network.connect(bustype='kvaser', channel=0, bitrate=250000)
  File "/test/Can_T1/venv/Lib/site-packages/canopen/network.py", line 112, in connect
    self.bus = can.interface.Bus(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/test/Can_T1/venv/Lib/site-packages/can/interface.py", line 120, in __new__
    bus = cls(channel, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/test/Can_T1/venv/Lib/site-packages/can/interfaces/kvaser/canlib.py", line 437, in __init__
    canGetNumberOfChannels(ctypes.byref(num_channels))
NameError: name 'canGetNumberOfChannels' is not defined
```

Is there any way to define 'canGetNumberOfChannels'?

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the canlib on your machine as well. Right now, you just have installed the SDK. If you are running on linux you have to install libcanlib.so on your machine. Take a look at the part that is related to your operating system on this link: https://pypi.org/project/canlib/

Comment: Hi Vahid,
i have canlib already installed, i reinstalled it, just to be sure.
but same error message appears :/

Comment: Can you run "dkms status" and send the result